# Any relation between period numbers and automorphic function?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

According to some scholar's research, period number may be some evaluation of Zeta function. Now, I wander whether there is any relation between  period numbers and automorphic function?

Comment: Particular values of L-functions is a complicated subject. What is the context ?

Comment: @reuns evaluation of automorphic function $f(x)$at algebraic $x$ is a period number, I wander.

Comment: @reuns Automorphic L-function

Comment: So what about the simplest case $\zeta$ ?